# ANTLR sub rule does not match when the parent rule is missing following token

Tags: antlr4

Consider the following simple grammar using ANTLR 4.7.1.

```
grammar Grammar;

ID: [a-z];
DOT: '.';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
SEMICOLON: ';';
LT: '<';
GT: '>';

term
    : ID LT ID GT LPAREN expr RPAREN # CallExpr
    | ID                             # Id
    | LPAREN expr RPAREN             # ParenExpr
    ;

expr
    : term DOT?               # PrimaryExpr
    | expr bop=(GT | LT) expr # BinaryExpr
    ;

update : expr SEMICOLON ;
```

When matching the snippet `a<b>(c)` against the rule `expr`, ANTLR reports that there is an ambiguity, as the expression can be either a `PrimaryExpr`, or a `BinaryExpr` with one of its operands is also a `BinaryExpr`. That's expected and it is a feature of the language that we develop. Thanks to the priority, the parser prefers the former, which is what we want.

When `a<b>(c);` is matched against `update`, everything also works as expected - there is an ambiguity, but the `PrimaryExpr` has precedence.

However, when I try to match `a<b>(c)` against `update`, I expect that apart from reporting missing semicolon, there is the same ambiguity. What happens instead is that only the `BinaryExpr` rule is matched. This is an issue, because such a snippet can appear in a code being written, and it causes the editor plugin autocomplete (and other features) to work incorrectly. Any pointers to why that happens and how to fix it?

Things I've experimented with, that merely increased the confusion further:

- When the `BinaryExpr` rule is removed, then `a<b>(c)` matches `update` through `PrimaryExpr` (with missing semicolon). How can ANTLR fallback to a different derivation when I remove the one it uses, yet do not report ambiguity?
- When `DOT?` is removed from `PrimaryExpr`, the issue is gone.
- When using custom reporting with `update : expr (SEMICOLON | {notifyErrorListeners("Missing ';'");})`, the issue is gone.

We can use the third option to fix the issue, it doesn't seem to break anything in our test suite, but I strongly feel I am not fixing the root cause and missing something fundamental which will bite us later.

I've found somewhat similar issue https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1545, but that one is already fixed.